# How to use DangerousAddRef when async native call

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

When calling a native function that takes IntPtr I understand how to do it with a Sync native function.

```
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    public static void Operation(SafeHandle handle)
    {
        var mustReleaseSafeHandle = false;
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try
        {
            handle.DangerousAddRef(ref mustReleaseSafeHandle);
            if (mustReleaseSafeHandle) WinAPI.Operation(handle.DangerousGetHandle());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mustReleaseSafeHandle) handle.DangerousRelease();
        }
    }
```

How do I ensure the DangerousRelease happens when the native function is async?

Here is a pseudo example of my async attempt to add more context as Hans Passant suggests.

```
    public static unsafe void Operation(SafeHandle fileHandle, SafeHandle nativeMemoryHandle, int offset)
    {
        var mustReleaseSafeHandle = false;
        var ioCompletionCallback = new IOCompletionCallback((code, bytes, overlap) =>
        {
            if (mustReleaseSafeHandle) nativeMemoryHandle.DangerousRelease();
            Overlapped.Free(overlap);
        });
        var overlapped = new Overlapped();
        var nativeOverlapped = overlapped.Pack(ioCompletionCallback, null);
        nativeMemoryHandle.DangerousAddRef(ref mustReleaseSafeHandle);
        if (mustReleaseSafeHandle)
        {
            var memoryStartLocation = IntPtr.Add(nativeMemoryHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), offset);
            if (!WinAPI.Operation(fileHandle, memoryStartLocation, offset, nativeOverlapped))
            {
                nativeMemoryHandle.DangerousRelease();
                Overlapped.Free(nativeOverlapped);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Overlapped.Free(nativeOverlapped);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clearly you should call it when the native function is completed.  You left no breadcrumbs at all to give specific advice beyond that.

Comment: So the native function will call back into the CLR because it's using a IOCompletionCallback and ThreadPool.BindHandle.  I know that I can call it in the callback but is that reliable?  Without being in a CER I imagine it could fail because of async exceptions.